# SSH MySQL Dump when password has special chars

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I need to do an export of a DB and I am using the following command.

`mysqldump -u USERNAME -pQP)u3V69S( DATABASE_NAME > backup.sql`

I get an error saying `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ')'`

I have a space after the `-u` but not after the `-p`. My password has parenthesis. How do I get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply omit the password but include a -p so you get a password prompt

Otherwise you could escape the characters

Comment: I do that, then I get a blank new line `>` but when I input my password I just get a new blank line. Any ideas?

Comment: Escape the ( and ) or otherwise surround the entire -p argument with single quotes which will treat it as a string literal